# Substring sql nvarchar value from start to first non-int character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, integer, substring, nvarchar

Have a numeric nvarchar values with some "extra-symbols" For example **1/2, 9/6, 14A** They allways starts with number.
How can I substring this "extra-symbols" values from start to index of first non-int character? The example line must be **1, 9, 14**
Something like

```
SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX(Value, /*Here must be all symbols except numbers*/))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the query:

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ColumnName+'a')-1) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Seems like PATINDEX return "-1"

Comment: Yes, this column have only int values and int with extra symbols values. On extra symbols values PATINDEX returns index and on only int values returns -1

Comment: How about this `SELECT LEFT(ColumnName,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ColumnName+'a')-1) FROM TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ColumnName) WHEN  0 THEN ColumnName
ELSE LEFT(ColumnName,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', ColumnName)-1) END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that avoids appending a character to every row in the table:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, 1, COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', col)-1, -1), 255)) 
  FROM dbo.mytable;
```